# regex - keep / remove same character

Tags: regex

I want to remove the apostrophes ' but only those between bracket.

My example is something like this :

```
'keep apostrophes' ('remove apostrophes')
```

I proceed like this :

```
[^a-z()\s]
```

but then it removes all apostrophes. I don't know a way to combine everything together.

Comment: What **language** are you using?

Comment: Why don't you replace all the (' and ') with ( and ) ?

Comment: And could you have data as such? `('foo' and 'bar')`?

Comment: @demostene because I want to do everything in once. The text i want to edit is very long

Comment: @hwnd the text i want to edit have only ('one word').

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following pattern:

```
\('([^']+)'\)
```

The back-reference, $1, will be stripped out of apostrophes.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Working example @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dD9hN6/1)

### Update #1

To accomplish your second request, please use the following pattern:

```
'([^']+)'\s*(?=(?:\sand|\sor|\)))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Working example @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oJ0xQ7/1)

#### Note

- The usage of positive look-ahead in order to accurately match all the appearances of `'words'` inside `'()'`
- The usage of regular expressions for this task is overkilling. (What programming language are you using to perform this task?)

Comment: What if you have the following text: 'keep apostrophes' ('remove apostrophes' and 'some more')

Comment: it just removed the whole expression : ('remove apostrophes') - I just want something like this in the end : 'keep apostrophes' (remove apostrophes). See answers below which helped me.

Comment: @coy8149; Is this task related to a text-replace in a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

```
'(?=[^(]*\))
```

You can use `lookahead` here.See demo.Replace by `empty string`.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/28

Comment: Thank you for the hyperlink. I _do_ like this tool

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I need! I will try to understand how your regex works. Thank you.